# Outlook client add-ins: links and JS redirects to other domain, open a new browser tab

Tags: office-js, appdomain, outlook-web-addins

My site is domaina.com. when i execute this code on Microsoft Edge DevTools Preview:

```
location.href = domainb.com/xxx/xxx
```

it can't redirect to the domainb.com on the right site add-on panel, it open my default browser to load my links.

I have add domainb.com to my manifest like this one:

```
<AppDomain>https://domainb.com</AppDomain>
```

when i execute code like below:

```
var displayUrl = "https://domainb.com";
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(displayUrl, { height: 75, width: 40 }, function(result) {
    console.log('displayDialogAsync: ');
    console.log(result);
});
```

The Edge DevTools will console log an error result like below:

```
[object Object]: {error: Object, status: "failed", value: undefined}

error: Object
code: 12004
message: "The domain of the URL is not included in the AppDomains element in the manifest, and is not subdomain of source location."
name: "Display Dialog Error"

__proto__: Object
status: "failed"
value: undefined

__proto__: Object
```

But in fact,
I have add domainb.com to my manifest:

```
<AppDomains>
<AppDomain>https://domainb.com</AppDomain>
<AppDomains>
```

But it is useless for

```
Window 10 1903 Verison OS build: 18362.535
Outlook client: Verison 1911 (Build 12228.20364 Click-to-Run) MSO (16.0.12228.20322) 64Bit.
```

I think that was caused by Edge engine. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins

For more details :https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/917

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC when zou open the Dialog with `displayDialogAsync` the url you pass has to be on the localhost (e.g. `https://localhost:3000/dialog.html`), from there you can redirect to whatever site you have added to `<AppDomains>`

```
<!-- dialog.html -->
...
<script>
Office.initialize = () => {
  window.location.href = 'https://url_included_in_app_domains' // domainb.com/xxx/xxx
}
...
</script>
```

Comment: hi lumpenstein, thank you so much for your solution. i think it's a workaround for me to use displayDialogAsync. But i still want to use window.location.href on the task panel(without displayDialogAsync) which is **messageReadTaskPaneUrl** tag on the manifast.xml. it will open a new browser tab. Do you have any suggestion for this case? appreciated that!

Comment: Sadly not, but I remember having read the same question once, can't find the link though :/

Comment: have find the mistake. for more detail and solution please see: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/917

Comment: Glad you found the error :) TL:DR for others: AppDomains in manifest does not accept wildcards and has to include the protocol.